# PHP/MYSQL Image upload to server linked to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do write news system to my site where I will upload image to folder on server and add link to this image to mysql. In the end display text and image on site. 
I know how to upload file on server but what to do later... I don't know. 
Can someone help me with this?
I don't need ready script, just some hints how to do it.

Comment: Just save image name to database, since path to image will stay the same. When displaying image, use `echo "<img src='path/to/img{$imageNameFromDB}'/>"` to display image

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite unexperienced with php and mysql so I didn't even thought about so simple method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you already saved the link in the database..

Just do the following:

```
<img src="/uploads/<?php echo $imglink;?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

in your script for uploading you should add an insert in database, for example upload.php :

```
// script upload :
// ....
// ....
// ....
$description = "your text for image";
//$image_name : name extracted from path image. 

// script insert :
$stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO table_name (description, image) VALUES (:description, :image)");
$stmt -> bindParam(':description', 'John');
$stmt -> bindParam(':image', $image_name);
$stmt -> execute();
```

to view results for example in list.php :

```
//========================================
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Print results :
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row["description"] . "<br/>";
    echo "<img src='path/to/img".$row['image']."'/>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $query=mysql_query("select * from image");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array)
{
echo "<img src='/uploads/'".$row['imglink']."' height='200' width='200'>"
}
```